# MVC 4 Async Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC 4 i created following async method in controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
{
    string str  = await TestClient() ;
    return View() ;
}
```

**Controller Name : Home 
Action Name :Test**
When my controller class inherits from "AsyncController" base class then `http://localhost/Home/Test` dosent work , even debugger is not hit on the action method . But When my controller class inherits from "Controller" base class then it works fine

I am not really sure about the difference it creates based on base class used

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4#ChoosingSyncVasync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncController` is the older way of implementing an asynchronous controller; use `Controller` in all modern code, including `async` code.